# IIS app pools, worker processes, app domains

Tags: asp.net, iis

Can anyone explain the differences, in IIS, between application pools, worker processes and app domains? Also, how do they work together? I've read a couple of articles but it's still a little confusing.

1. Does each website created in IIS becomes an application?
2. Is each application associated with one worker process?
3. Where do app domains come into the picture?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I try to say them with other words.

In a server you can have many asp.net sites that runs together. Each one site is an **app domain**.

You must assign to each of them one **application pool**. Many application domains (sites) can have the same application pool, and because they have the same application pool they run under the same processes, and under the same account - and they have the same settings of the pool. If this pool restarts, then all sites under that pools restarts.

Now each pool can have one or more **worker process**. Each worker process is a different program that's run your site, have their alone static variables, they different start stop calls etc. Different worker process are not communicate together, and the only way to exchange data is from common files or a common database. If you have more than one worker process and one of them make long time calculations, then the other can take care to handle the internet calls and show content.

When you assign many worker process to a single pool then you make the called **web garden** and your site is like to be run from more than one computer if a computer is one processing machine.

[image: app domains, with pools and processes]

Each worker process can have many threads.

How the more worker process affect you:
When you have **one worker process** everything is more simple, among your application all static variables are the same, and you use the [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) to synchronize them.
When you assign **more than one worker process** then you still continue to use the `lock` for static variables, static variables are not different among the many runs of your site, and if you have some common resource (e.g. the creation of a thumbnail on the disk) then you need to synchronize your worker process with [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

One more note. Its sounds that when you make **more worker process** then you may have more smooth asynchronous page loads. There is a small issue with the session handler of asp.net that is lock the entire process for a page load - that is good and not good depend if you know it and handle it - or change it.

So let talk about one site only with many worker process. Here you face the issue that you need to synchronize your common resource change with `Mutex`. But the pages/handlers that use session they are not asynchronous because the session locks them. This is good for start because you avoid to make this synchronization of many points your self.

Some questions on this topic:
[Web app blocked while processing another web app on sharing same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426673/web-app-blocked-while-processing-another-web-app-on-sharing-same-session)
[jQuery Ajax calls to web service seem to be synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052401/jquery-ajax-calls-to-web-service-seem-to-be-synchronous)
[ASP.NET Server does not process pages asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284530/asp-net-server-does-not-process-pages-asynchronously)
[Replacing ASP.Net's session entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989648/replacing-asp-nets-session-entirely)

Now this session lock is not affect different sites.

Among different sites the more worked process can help to not the one site block the other with long running process.
Also among different sites the more pools also can help, because each pool have at least one worked process, but remember and see by your self using the process explorer, each working process takes more memory of your computer, and one big server with 16G memory and one SQL server can not have too many different worked process - for example on a server with 100 shared sites, you can not have 100 different pools.

Comment: I'm figuring out it's different from the way how IIS 5 handles it compared to IIS 6 and above. So in IIS 5 you have one Worker process and multiple app domains in it compared to IIS 6 you have multiple worker processes (w3wp.exe) one for each application pool.In IIS 6.0 inetinfo redirects to different worker process depending on the request . Am I right here ?  Here is my source http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/iis/ASPNETInternalsIISAndTheProcessModel.aspx

Comment: @user460103 Yes iis5 is have one worker process (multiple app domains can have only with a small hack, but they not work together.) When you have on one site many worker process, then yes iis6 can redirect you to different worker process.

Comment: Does the IIS spin up a new process for every web request? Or does it spin up a new thread?

Comment: @variable Spin up a new thread - the process are stay up and running all the time, or they recycle the way you have set them up on the pool...

Comment: Ok if there are multiple processes, then how does sessions work - I thought session is per process

Comment: @variable The session have a common to all processes database (sql or memory). The sql session is something you setting up with a database server (make the connection, see the tables etc) , the memory session is a service that keeps the data common to all processes, and asp.net communicate with the same service, no matter the process or thread- Also the session is lock to a user base on a cookie that asp.net add to that user - so the cookie is keep the connection of the session with the user

Answer (score 18):

- One IIS server may have multiple application pools.
- One web application binds to one application pool.
- One application pool may have more than one worker process (when Web Garden is enable).
- One worker process can have multiple app domains. One app domain lives only in one worker process.
- One app domain may have multiple threads. One thread can be shared by different app domains in different time.

The meaning to ASP.NET developers: to make your web site scalable, don't use in-proc session and don't use static class variable lock for synchronization.

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes, though not every application is a website. You can have an application that is nested *under* a website.
2. Yes, every application has to have one worker process (application pool), though one application pool can server several applications. A single web application can be distributed (web garden/farm) meaning that it will run in multiple processes.
3. Each process will run in its own app domain (every application pool is a separate app domain).

---

From MSDN.

[Create a Web Application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> An application is a grouping of content at the root level of a Web site or a grouping of content in a separate folder under the Web site's root directory.

[Application Pools](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools):

> An application pool defines a group of one or more worker processes, configured with common settings that serve requests to one or more applications that are assigned to that application pool. Because application pools allow a set of Web applications to share one or more similarly configured worker processes, they provide a convenient way to isolate a set of Web applications from other Web applications on the server computer. Process boundaries separate each worker process; therefore, application problems in one application pool do not affect Web sites or applications in other application pools. Application pools significantly increase both the reliability and manageability of your Web infrastructure.

Comment: So IIS process has multiple app domains (application pools) and every application pool can multiple websites. So is it that multiple websites reside in single app domain ? What if something goes wrong in one website does it take down the whole app domain and all the websites residing in it ?

Comment: @user460103 If you crash a pool, then yes all the sites that are connected to it they stop - and restarts again.

Comment: 2. No. An application could possibly span more than one worker processes if a web garden is configured.

Comment: @Wiktor - I did not preclude that. However, updated answer to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

From the source link:-http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2007/09/02/application-vs-appdomain.aspx

> An application is an IIS term, but it's one that ASP.NET utilizes. 
>   Essentially it creates a sandbox, or a set of boundaries to separate
>   different sites, or parts of sites, from the others.
>
> An AppDomain is a .NET term.  (In IIS7, AppDomains play a larger role
>   within IIS, but for the most part it's an ASP.NET term)

The worker process is used to process the request of the web application.