# Whether the Default App pool crashes and shut down will affect other App pools running in the same farm / IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6

We have Windows 2003 Server IIS 6.0  and Windows 2008 Server IIS 7.0

Issue : In IIS 6.0, when Default App pool crashes it shut down other App pools as well.

Whether the Default App pool crashes and shut down will affect other App pools running in the same farm  / IIS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Other Pools

One pool can affect other in this cases.

1. Lock some global resource that the rest need to access and all pools gets time outs.
2. Eat the servers power with bad loops.

Each pool have their space that work aside from the other, so general speaking you need to look for what they have common, like if you use session database and the one locks it for long time, and the other is gets time outs many time together with the first one and fell also on Rapid-fail protection.

### Pool it self

The pool is connected with many apps, so when this pool crash, is affect and all apps/web sites that are connected with this.

When this is a problem.

1. When the pool crash many times and is felt on the "**Rapid-Fail Protection**" that make the pool to permanently shut down.
2. When some site is keep the pool inside a loop that eats all resource of it and the power of your server.

here is an example : [How do I crash the App Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044752/how-do-i-crash-the-app-pool/3045137#3045137)

For the first case you must go to your pool and turn off the "**Rapid-Fail Protection**". For the second case you need to locate the problem and isolate.

More to read:
[Rapid Fail Protection](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Dec/19/IIS-7-and-Rapid-Fail-Protection)
[Configuring Rapid-Fail Protection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787273(v=ws.10).aspx)
[IIS app pools, worker processes, app domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105345/iis-app-pools-worker-processes-app-domains/14105747#14105747)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Aristos. My Question is , whether one pool crash will affect other pools sitting in the same IIS. I agree with you one pool has multiple apps and crash of one app will end the pool shut down.

Comment: @goofyui Oh, maybe did not fully understand... you talk about the rest pools. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Aristos, My real problem is ..when my default app pool is crashed / shutdown it makes other app pool to shut down.  I have 2-3 webservices running on my default app pool. I wonder, whether i have to make each and every application as separate pool

Comment: @goofyui My suggestion is to use if you can the "process explorer" and find the "bad" sites that make the problem and fix them or isolate.

Comment: @goofyui it better not to have many pools (one for each application). Just separate them base on what they do, how many power and memory they use, how critical they are.

Comment: Oh great thanks. My understanding is that , Having too many pools will also a bad way of setting up. So if default pool crashes, there is a possibility of other pools to get crash.  To handle this, isolate every application as individual pool

Comment: investigate the application that have the problem and isolate only this one. Then fix it. Also check what happened with process explorer (if you have access to the server)