# Alternate for Session variable in c #, Can we use class and its object to store a value instead of session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, session-variables

I am building a web application.  The authentication will be managed by the website, that is not my concern.  What i need to store is the `UserID` in some place.

Once they open the application I will be able to get their `UserID`.  I was previously using a Session variable to store this.  Can I create a class say:

```
static string _UserID;

public static string UserDetails
{
    get
    {
        return _UserID;
    }
    set
    {
        _globalValue = \\value from webpage;
    }
}
```

and use `UserDetails._UserID` instead of assigning it to a session variable?!
The website's session server is not very reliable so I thought I could use this way.
Will this work?

I learnt from the answers that the variables will be overwritten for each user which is not what I want!!

Will it be the same scenario if i `create an instance of this class` in handler and assign the `UserID` to it??

are there any other way where I can make its scope limited only to one user i.e UserID with which I login should be same and if new user login to the application it must not be overwritten?? what is the disadvantage of using this method??
Is this method good if I use only one page and assign the object in the launch of the applciation ??

Comment: if you are using forms authentication you can keep this data in the authentication cookie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static variables persist for the life of the app domain. So the two things that will cause your static variables to 'reset' is an app domain restart or the use of a new class.

The main problem is that static variables are **shared across ALL USERS**, and that is dangerous in your case that you pretend to store an UserID inside it. If you want to store
per user sessoin ID you should use `Session`

You can find more info here:

[Lifetime of ASP.NET Static Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919095/lifetime-of-asp-net-static-variable)

Comment: Is there any other way!? what if we create instances of the class and then use its objects?? or can we create classes that are not static and then use them??

Comment: Best is using Session, because creating instances of the classes with make them die when the scope finishes, like going to another web page.

Comment: Yes but I have only around 3 pages and the server which holds the session is not very reliable!! thats why I am looking for an alternate 
also we have been asked not to use cookies

Comment: @vignesh did you finally used a session variable?

Answer (score 2):

`static` filed will be shared between all users that means you would overwrite it for everyone. If you do not want to store it in `Session` you may store it in `cookie` (encrypted if security is important).

Comment: Will this be the same scenario if i Create an instance of the class and use that object??

Comment: No, as long as it is not a static but you would have to create an instance after each request and fill it with data. Normal objects are valid only for given request and are destroyed after.