# Dictionary losing key value pairs when time passes

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

Something strange is happening in my web application. I have a static dictionary that I use to hold a collection of simple objects that hold two variables:

```
static Dictionary<string, linkButtonObject> linkButtonDictonary = new Dictionary<string, linkButtonObject>();
```

I have a gridview with linkbuttons, data about each one is associated with its button.UniqueId in the Dictionary:

```
protected void hoursReportGridView_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("taskLinkButton");
     linkButtonObject currentRow = new linkButtonObject();
     currentRow.storyNumber = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;
     currentRow.TaskName = e.Row.Cells[5].Text;
     linkButtonDictonary.Add(btn.UniqueID, currentRow);
}
```

Then when the linkbutton is clicked I pull look up the values in the dictionary using the UniqueId, use them in a SQL query and use the retrieved data to populate a gridview, labels and show a popup:

```
protected void taskLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create linkbutton object from sender
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    //get a list of data relevant to column
    string[] infoData = getInfoData(linkButtonDictonary[btn.UniqueID].storyNumber, 
        linkButtonDictonary[btn.UniqueID].TaskName);
    //assign content of list to labels and gridview
    productDatabaseLabel.Text = infoData[0];
    storyNumberDatabaseLabel.Text = infoData[1];
    taskDatabaseLabel.Text = infoData[2];
    pointPersonDatabaseLabel.Text = infoData[3];
    SqlDataSource6.SelectParameters["storynumber"].DefaultValue = linkButtonDictonary[btn.UniqueID].storyNumber;
    SqlDataSource6.SelectParameters["tasktitle"].DefaultValue = linkButtonDictonary[btn.UniqueID].TaskName;
    infoGridView.DataBind();
    //show popup
    MPE.Show();
}
```

This all works great and I can click any of the linkbuttons and they correctly create and populate the popup and show it.

My issue is that if I leave the page idle for a few minuites and then click a linkbutton I get the error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Why is the dictionary declared as static? Does this issue occur if you remove the static modifier?

Comment: If i remove the static I get the exception every time.

Comment: What exception is it? KeyNotFound or null?

Comment: The KeyNotFound exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will lose the static data every time the AppDomain ends, which it will do from time-to-time, for example when IIS decides to recycle your worker process.

See this from somebody who can explain it much better than me! [Lifetime of ASP.NET Static Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919095/lifetime-of-asp-net-static-variable)

You need to seek out an alternative data storage pattern. Statics are not the way forward for what you are looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Can you either attach a debugger to your website, or add some diagnostic code? What's the content of the dictionary when the exception occurs?

My guess is that the button's `UniqueID` is not constant, that the dictionary still contains your data, but the IDs no longer match. Alternatively, maybe the process/appdomain is recycled, and the dictionary is somehow emptied.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to me. If you are looking only for a temporary storage storage. Create your own `KeyValuePair` class then put it in a `List<>` or in an `object[ ]`.

```
 class Tupol
    {
        public Tupol() { }
        public Tupol(string key,string value) { }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Initialize:

```
List<Tupol> temp = new List<Tupol>();
```

Get value:

```
foreach(Tupol in temp)
{ if(temp.Key == "foo") { Debug.WriteLine(temp.Value); break; } }
```

In this instance i choose to be both my "**Key**" and "**Value**" pairs as ***string***. (*This works for me.*)