# ASP.NET web application life-cycle/lifetime

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

In PHP (Apache + mod_php) the interpreter is restarted on every request. This is the execution model even if using PHP-fpm which keeps a few interpreters ready for requests.

Does an ASP.NET web app persist in IIS application pool waiting for requests or is there a new thread/process per request?

For example, would a static class variable persist across requests when one of those requests initializes it?

Comment: Is your actual question _"How can I persist application-level variables in ASP.NET"_?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lifetime of ASP.NET Static Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919095/lifetime-of-asp-net-static-variable)

Comment: @CodeCaster the static variables context sparked the question but I'm more interested in whether the application persists across requests or if it is restarted as PHP is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the value is persisted across requests.

A static class variable's (a field's) value is persisted and shared across all usage of the class (whether via an instantiated object or through the class reference itself). See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691162(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691162%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: but does the application persist across requests?

Comment: Yes, the value is persisted across requests.

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to be, it can be lost due to an app pool recycle in between any two requests.