# Multiple instance of custom class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have a simple question which is confusing ..

Assume I have a class as Employee as follows

```
public Class Employee {

   public Int EmpID { get; set ;}
   public string EmpName { get; set ; }
}
```

Suppose web application  creates instance of the object as follow

```
Employee obj = new Employee()
obj.EmpID = Int32.Parse(txtID.text)
obj.EmpName = txtName.text
```

If multiple instance of web application are executed(like 2 or 3 users using the web application at the same time) , then will the values of obj gets mixed up ?. Or is it unique to instance of web application running .

Comment: instances with `new` are different references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then will the values of obj gets mixed up ?.

No never since you haven't defined class `Employee` [nor its properties] as `static`.

> Or is it unique to instance of web application running .

Yes, they are unique. No matter, how many users is accessing your page, they will have a different instance of `Employee` object referring (or) pointing to different memory address in Heap area.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Thanks for the comment. Edited the answer with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's Unique per object instance you create regardless if its the same user or a different one and is destroyed after it's out of scope or after the request by the GC.  Unless you use static variables(see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919095/lifetime-of-asp-net-static-variable)) or put that instance of the object into a session variable (unique to the user's session) or cache.