# Trying to figure out how to share a variable between .net code behind subs

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to figure out how to set the ID variable in the `itemCommand` block, and then share it in the `PagePropertiesChanged` block.

I am wondering if this is possible to do?

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do,

```
Public Shared ID As Integer

 Private Sub DataListCategories_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As DataListCommandEventArgs) Handles DataListCategories.ItemCommand

    If (e.CommandName.Equals("ClickCategory")) Then

            ID = e.CommandArgument

    End if

 End sub

 Private Sub ListViewGallery_PagePropertiesChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListViewGallery.PagePropertiesChanged


    Me.ListViewGallery.DataSource = Dal.GetPhotographyByCategory(ID)
        Me.ListViewGallery.DataBind()

 End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sharing a variable between the subs"?

Comment: Are you trying to get the value to persist between postbacks?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to persist the ID in a Shared variable (static in C#) between post backs but you must understand the nature of shared/static variables in ASP.NET.

This is covered well in [Lifetime of ASP.NET Static Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919095/lifetime-of-asp-net-static-variable)

You can persist the ID using the Session object like:

```
Session("ID") = ID
```

Or use a something like a ASP.NET hidden field

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="IDField" runat="server" value="0"/>
```

Set it like this:

```
IDField.Value = ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sort of confused at what you are saying. I think you are saying put a hidden field in the html, and call it in code behind using a findcontrol?

can it not be done the other way?