# Lifetime of the Static variable issue in WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I can't wrap my head around this issue, where I am assigning a instance to a static class and variable during `Appication_Start` and the variable become null after a few days.

```cs
public static class IocFactory
{
    private static IContainer _appscopeContainer;

    public static void Register(IContainer container = null){
        _appscopeContainer = container
    }

    public static Instance{
        get { return _appscopeContainer; }
    }
}
```

And I assign an instance to the variable upon `Appication_Start`, I would expected that the `_appscopeContainer` presists.

```vb
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim appContainer As IContainer = new Container()
    'register framework 4.0 class to container...

    IocFactory.Register(appContainer)
End Sub
```

On `Begin_Request` I would build a child container and store it to the HttpContext request cache, and an error will sometimes throw saying that the `_appscopeContainer` is null after a few days, I have tried recycling the application and it will behivaour normally.

```vb
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim requestContainer As IContainer = IocFactory.Instance.BeginLifetimeScope(Tags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag)
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919095/lifetime-of-asp-net-static-variable

Comment: Where in your project structure is the static class?

Comment: Static variables won't be nulled "by themselves". To understand what's going on just implement some persistent logging for the following: 1) static constructor of `IocFactory` 2) Every call to `IocFactory.Register` 3) constructor of application instance 4) first line of `Application_Start`. Then wait for NRE, then analyze.

Comment: The static class is in a separate dll assembly. But to my understanding dll shouldn't get unloaded right?