# Async Web Service call not consistently asynchronous

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, task-parallel-library

I'm having issues creating an asynchronous web service using the Task Parallel Library with ASP.NET Web API 2. I make an asynchronous call to a method `StartAsyncTest` and create a cancellation token to abort the method. I store the token globally and then retrieve it and call it from a second method `CancelAsyncTest`. Here is the code:

```
// Private Global Dictionary to hold text search tokens
private static Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource> TextSearchLookup
    = new Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>();

/// <summary>
/// Performs an asynchronous test using a Cancellation Token
/// </summary>
[Route("StartAsyncTest")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<WsResult<long>> StartAsyncTest(string sSearchId)
{
    Log.Debug("Method: StartAsyncTest; ID: " + sSearchId + "; Message: Entering...");

    WsResult<long> rWsResult = new WsResult<long>
    {
        Records = -1
    };

    try
    {
        var rCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        {
            var rCancellationToken = rCancellationTokenSource.Token;

            // Set token right away in TextSearchLookup
            TextSearchLookup.Add("SyncTest-" + sSearchId, rCancellationTokenSource);

            HttpContext.Current.Session["SyncTest-" + sSearchId] =
                rCancellationTokenSource;

            try
            {
                // Start a New Task which has the ability to be cancelled 
                var rHttpContext = (HttpContext)HttpContext.Current;

                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    HttpContext.Current = rHttpContext;

                    int? nCurrentId = Task.CurrentId;

                    StartSyncTest(sSearchId, rCancellationToken);

                }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException e)
            {
                Log.Debug("Method: StartAsyncText; ID: " + sSearchId
                    + "; Message: Cancelled!");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        rWsResult.Result = "ERROR";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ex.Message) == false)
        {
            rWsResult.Message = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    // Remove token from Dictionary
    TextSearchLookup.Remove(sSearchId);
    HttpContext.Current.Session[sSearchId] = null;
    return rWsResult;
}

private void StartSyncTest(string sSearchId, CancellationToken rCancellationToken)
{
    // Spin for 1100 seconds
    for (var i = 0; i < 1100; i++)
    {
        if (rCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            rCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        Log.Debug("Method: StartSyncTest; ID: " + sSearchId
            + "; Message: Wait Pass #" + i + ";");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    TextSearchLookup.Remove("SyncTest-" + sSearchId);

    HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("SyncTest-" + sSearchId);
}

[Route("CancelAsyncTest")]
[HttpGet]
public WsResult<bool> CancelAsyncTest(string sSearchId)
{
    Log.Debug("Method: CancelAsyncTest; ID: " + sSearchId
        + "; Message: Cancelling...");

    WsResult<bool> rWsResult = new WsResult<bool>
    {
        Records = false
    };

    CancellationTokenSource rCancellationTokenSource =
        (CancellationTokenSource)HttpContext.Current.Session["SyncTest-" + sSearchId];

    // Session doesn't always persist values. Use TextSearchLookup as backup
    if (rCancellationTokenSource == null)
    {
        rCancellationTokenSource = TextSearchLookup["SyncTest-" + sSearchId];
    }

    if (rCancellationTokenSource != null)
    {
        rCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        TextSearchLookup.Remove("SyncTest-" + sSearchId);
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("SyncTest-" + sSearchId);

        rWsResult.Result = "OK";
        rWsResult.Message = "Cancel delivered successfully!";
    }
    else
    {
        rWsResult.Result = "ERROR";
        rWsResult.Message = "Reference unavailable to cancel task"
            + " (if it is still running)";
    }

    return rWsResult;
}
```

After I deploy this to IIS, the first time I call `StartAsyncTest` and then `CancelAsyncTest` (via the REST endpoints), both requests go through and it cancels as expected. However, the second time, the `CancelAsyncTest` request just hangs and the method is only called after `StartAsyncTest` completes (after 1100 seconds). I don't know why this occurs. `StartAsyncTest` seems to highjack all threads after it's called once. I appreciate any help anyone can provide!

Comment: First, do you mind if I ask why the task you want to perform is asynchronous? Does it take up a lot of processor power, or is it because you have to wait on something like I/O?

Comment: Also, while I can't say this is a definitive answer, there's a lot you can get wrong if you pass HttpContext to a different thread -- are you just using it to keep track of threads? Use a concurrent dictionary to keep track of that.

Comment: Does every request get a unique `sSearchId`?  It would cause issues if not.  You can probably drop the `Session` usage as I doubt a CTS will serialize/deserialize correctly for the usual flavour of that.  Also, change your sync wait to async; you can replace that whole `Task.Factory.StartNew...` with simply `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1100.0), rCancellationToken);`, which will throw a `TaskCanceledException` if the CTS is cancelled.

Comment: Yes, the real use case (this is just an example to show the problem) is searching a text file for a string, which takes up a lot of processor power. The `HttpContext` is passed to the thread because calling `Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't persist it. Also, every `sSearchId` is unique

Comment: Regarding the `Dictionary` that holds your cancellation sources in a static variable, take a look at this: [Lifetime of ASP.NET Static Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919095/lifetime-of-asp-net-static-variable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A colleague offered a alternative call to `Task.Factory.StartNew` (within `StartAsyncTest`):

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    StartSyncTest(sSearchId, rCancellationToken);
},
rCancellationToken, 
TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

This implementation seemed to solve the asynchronous issue. Now future calls to `CancelAsyncTest` succeed and cancel the task as intended.

Answer (score 4):

> I store the token globally and then retrieve it and call it from a second method CancelAsyncTest.

This is probably not a great idea. You can store these tokens "globally", but that's only "global" to a single server. This approach would break as soon as a second server enters the picture.

That said, `HttpContext.Current` shouldn't be assigned to, ever. This is most likely the cause of the odd behavior you're seeing. Also, if your real code is more complex than `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` - i.e., if it's actually *listening* to the `CancellationToken` - then the call to `Cancel` can execute the remainder of `StartSyncTest` from *within* the call to `Cancel`, which would cause considerable confusion over the value of `HttpContext.Current`.

To summarize:

- I recommend doing away with this approach completely; it won't work at all on web farms. Instead, keep your "task state" in an external storage system like a database.
- Don't pass `HttpContext` across threads.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would store the `CancellationToken` in an external DB?

Comment: @vinays84: You can't directly. You'll have to write your own system. E.g., you could have a `CancellationRequested` column that is polled by the executing task. Or you could use a pub/sub system like SignalR.